# Is there a way of providing a final transform method when chaining operations (like map reduce) in underscore.js?

Tags: functional-programming, underscore.js

(Really strugging to title this question, so if anyone has suggestions feel free.)

Say I wanted to do an operation like:

- take an array [1,2,3]
- multiply each element by 2 (map): [2,4,6]
- add the elements together (reduce): 12
- multiply the result by 10: 120

I can do this pretty cleanly in underscore using chaining, like so:

```js
arr = [1,2,3]
map = (el) -> 2*el
reduce = (s,n) -> s+n
out = (r) -> 10*r

reduced = _.chain(arr).map(map).reduce(reduce).value()
result = out(reduced)
```

However, it would be even nicer if I could chain the 'out' method too, like this:

```js
result = _.chain(arr).map(map).reduce(reduce).out(out).value()
```

Now this would be a fairly simple addition to a library like underscore. But my questions are:

- Does this 'out' method have a name in functional programming?
- Does this already exist in underscore (`tap` comes close, but not quite).

Comment: Did you see this thread https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/499? If you have a good real world example for this, you could try asking Jeremy why he though this pull request is inappropriate.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, apologies, that's CoffeeScript. `(r) -> 10*r` is the same as `function (r) { return 10*r; }`

Comment: @latentflip Interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question got me quite hooked. Here are some of my thoughts.

It feels like using underscore.js in 'chain() mode' breaks away from functional programming paradigm. Basically, instead of calling functions on functions, you're calling methods of an instance of a wrapper object in an OOP way.

I am using [underscore's chain()](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) myself here and there, but this question made me think. What if it's better to simply create more meaningful functions that can then be called in a sequence without having to use chain() at all. Your example would then look something like this:

```js
arr = [1,2,3]
double = (arr) -> _.map(arr, (el) -> 2 * el)
sum = (arr) -> _.reduce(arr, (s, n) -> s + n)
out = (r) -> 10 * r

result = out sum double arr
# probably a less ambiguous way to do it would be
result = out(sum(double arr))
```

Looking at real functional programming languages (as in .. much more functional than JavaScript), it seems you could do exactly the same thing there in an even simpler manner. Here is the same program written in Standard ML. Notice how calling map with only one argument returns another function. There is no need to wrap this map in another function like we did in JavaScript.

```js
val arr = [1,2,3];
val double = map (fn x => 2*x);
val sum = foldl (fn (a,b) => a+b) 0;
val out = fn r => 10*r;

val result = out(sum(double arr))
```

Standard ML also lets you create operators which means we can make a little 'chain' operator that can be used to call those functions in a more intuitive order.

```js
infix 1 |>;
fun x |> f = f x;

val result = arr |> double |> sum |> out
```

I also think that this underscore.js chaining has something similar to monads in functional programming, but I don't know much about those. Though, I have feeling that this kind of data manipulation pipeline is not something you would typically use monads for.

I hope someone with more functional programming experience can chip in and correct me if I'm wrong on any of the points above.

**UPDATE**

Getting slightly off topic, but one way to creating partial functions could be the following:

```js
// extend underscore with partialr function
_.mixin({
  partialr: function (fn, context) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return function () {
      return fn.apply(context, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).concat(args));
    };
  }
});
```

This function can now be used to create a partial function from any underscore function, because most of them take the input data as the first argument. For example, the sum function can now be created like

```js
var sum = _.partialr(_.reduce, this, function (s, n) { return s + n; });
sum([1,2,3]);
```

I still prefer arr |> double |> sum |> out over out(sum(double(arr))) though. Underscore's chain() is nice in that it reads in a more natural order.

Comment: Cheers @Karolis, well spotted that my approach isn't actually functional, as yes even the docs call 'chain() mode' the OO way of using underscore.

Comment: And I much prefer your new approach. Good thinking :)

Comment: I wish it was easier to create those smaller functions thought. Especially in vanilla JavaScript, writing smth like (arr) -> _.map(arr, (el) -> 2 * el) is a bit verbose. I'm looking into how _.compose or _.bind or partial or curry could help, but can't quite nail it..

Comment: It should basically be something like
sum = \_.partial(\_.reduce, (s, n) -> s + n))
or
sum = \_.curry(\_.reduce, (s, n) -> s + n))
or smth.. I'm just confused with the names

Comment: A partial function isn't the same as a partially-applied function. A partial function is one that is only defined for a subset of values in its domain type.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the name you are looking for, I think what you are trying to do is just a form of function application: you have an underscore object and you want to apply a function to its value. In underscore, you can define it like this:

```js
_.mixin({
  app: function(v, f) { return f (v); }
});
```

then you can pretty much do what you asked for:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
function m(el) { return 2*el; };
function r(s,n) { return s+n; };
function out(r) { return 10*r; };

console.log("result: " + _.chain(arr).map(m).reduce(r).app(out).value()));
```

Having said all that, I think using traditional typed functional languages like SML make this kind of think a lot slicker and give much lighter weight syntax for function composition. Underscore is doing a kind of jquery twist on functional programming that I'm not sure what I think of; but without static-type checking it is frustratingly easy to make errors!